# Drawing Vertical Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

is there any quick way to draw vertical plots with pgf-plots? I need to draw successive vertical lines for the plot below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
clip=false,
ylabel={},
xlabel=$$,
axis lines=middle,
xticklabels={},% if you don't want x tick labels
yticklabels={},% if you don't want y tick labels
xtick=\empty,% if you don't want x ticks
ytick=\empty,% if you don't want y ticks
extra x ticks={},
extra x tick labels={$\color{red}\bar{p}$,1.2},
extra tick style={major tick length=5pt, tick style={red, line width=0.1em}},
]

\addplot[domain=-0:2, samples=200, black, ultra thick] plot(\x,{-1+(1/\x^(1/3))});
\addplot[domain=-0:2, samples=200, black, ultra thick] plot(\y,{0.5});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way to draw a vertical line with `pgfplots` is to specify two coordinates:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot [red, dotted, thick] coordinates {(2,-1) (2,1)}
        node [right] {$x=2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```